# lines with 25+ words split when the first comma appears

Tags: python, linux, bash, text, split

I have a text file where lines longer than 25 words should be broken down:

Precisely, I would like the code to do the following:

1) Count the number of words in each line (word defined as anything separated by space character...so something like "sample-word." is still considered a word). If word count is less than or equal to 25, then simply return that line.

2) If false (greater than 25), then search the line from left to right for the first comma character, then split immediately after comma.

example:

```
line1: phrase from a test line, which I want to split, and I don't know how.
```

to

```
line1: phrase from a test line,
line2: which I want to split, and I don't know how.
```

3) If no comma characters are found then search the line from left to right for the first  "and " (including the space after *and* so it doesn't split a word like android) and split immediately before "and " (unlike before where the split was after).

example

```
line1: phrase from a long sentence and I want to split
```

to

```
line1: phrase from a long sentence
line2: and I want to split
```

5) if no "and " is found, then split the line at exactly after 25 words (this is what the other solutions in the links above can do).

6) loop the code from 1-5 to run 7 times  because even after even after a line is broken up the remaining line can still have more than 25 words. the code doesn't need be efficient or elegant, so I thought looping it is easiest way of coding it.

7) save to ouput.txt file.

Please note, I want the above breaks only for lines over 25 words... breaking up every comma, colon, semicolon, and "and" word is not what I is required.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No need to reinvent the wheel. You want the [`fold`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/fold.1.html) command:

```
fold -s -w25 file
```

Demo:

```
fold -s -w25 <<END
123456789.123456789.123456789.
phrase from a test line, which I want to split, and I don't know how.
END
```

```
123456789.123456789.12345
6789.
phrase from a test line,
which I want to split,
and I don't know how.
```

Comment: Hi Glenn Jackman, thank you. This comes a bit closer to what I need and is similar to suggestions from my links. However, before this I want the lines to be split by commas, and colons, and semicolonds (in the order noted in my question). Your solution is the last step. What would the code be? I don't have a coding background and am quite a newbie.